# How to insert value to text box using Angular Material [mat-form-field]

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to insert a value to text box [mat-form-field] using a function

```
addValue(){
...
}
```

Comment: @Barushmashasha can you explain more about your problem?

Comment: This is angular 101. Read almost any quick tutorial or demo (like [tour of heros](https://angular.io/tutorial)) of how angular works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `ngModel` and you can use it as follows:

in template add ngModel to your `textarea` or any input field:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea name="text" matInput [(ngModel)]="myText" placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
```

and in your TS file:

```
public myText= "";
...
addValue(){
 this.myText="Some special Text";
}
```

Working example: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mysryb)

Read more about [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

Comment: Thanks i move to angular from react and i New. I now read about this thanks.